# Jade/Pug w/ HTML data element

Tags: pug

I use the following line in my code with success:

```
.div(data-text='text')
```

but I am working on a multilingual site reading the languages w/JQuery from JSON. In this case, the usual way to put the text into a simple HTML p tag is:

```
p(tkey='text')
```

I would like to use the same method in the data-text div:

```
.div(data-text=(tkey='text'))
```

The problem is probably caused by the fact that I wanted to use it within a loop such as:

```
- for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    .div(data-text='data' + i)
- }
```

Is it possible? What is the syntax?

Thank you for all!

Comment: What is the HTML you'd like to be outputted?

Comment: It seems like: <div data-text=tkey="text"></div>

Comment: That's invalid HTML, one attribute can only have one property.  Do you mean <div data-text="{value of the tkey variable}"> ?

Answer (score 1):

Pug has a few constructs to loop, [docs are here](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html).

To do what you want I'd suggest using each:

```
each val in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  div(data-text= 'data' + val)
```

An alias of `each` is `for` so this does the same thing:

```
for val in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  div(data-text= 'data' + val)
```

If you have a larger number of values to iterate through then shift to the `while` syntax:

```
- var index = 0;
- var limit = 25;
while index < limit
    div(data-text= 'data' + index++)
```

However, you're usually looping through an existing array of objects such as a result set from a database.  If you want to use the index in the each loop then add that as the second argument:

```
- var results = ["Adam", "Bonnie", "Clara"];
each person, index in results
  p(data-text= 'data' + index)= person
```

Will produce this HTML:

```
<p data-text='data1'>Adam</p>
<p data-text='data2'>Bonnie</p>
<p data-text='data3'>Clara</p>
```

---

Also note that `.div` creates this HTML:

```
<div class="div"></div>
```

If you only want a div then leave out the leading period, `div` produces this:

```
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: I just tested it - div(data-text= "tkey='text'") produces <div data-text="tkey='text'">tkey</div>

Comment: Thank you for your effort, Graham! The problem is probably caused by the fact that I wanted to use it within a loop:

Comment: If you could edit your original question with those details (and more of your code) I'm pretty sure we can help you out here.